# Angular-Make delete button that have *ngIf condition always visible

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table

i need help about how to make my delete button always visible without click update button or a row first. I learn a tutorial from [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ5z9SFBlek). The project is using [angularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). He make the data clickable then it appears on the form and then he can update/delete it. What i need to do is make the delete button already visible for each row with the `*ngIf="ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey != null"` condition is still there.
If i change the condition to `...==null`", the delete button always visible but button become delete all data.

```js
//service.ts file
export class Product {
  $prdKey: string;
  prdName: string;
  prdCat: string; //category
  prdSup: string; //supplier
}

deleteProduct(key: string) {
  this.productList.remove(key);
}

updateProduct(prd: Product) {
  this.productList.update(prd.$prdKey, {
    prdName: prd.prdName,
    prdCat: prd.prdCat,
    prdSup: prd.prdSup,
  })
}
```

```js
//component.ts file

isVisible:boolean = true;

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  if (form.value.$prdKey == null) {
    this.ProductService.insertProduct(this.ProductService.selectedProduct);
  } else {
    this.ProductService.updateProduct(this.ProductService.selectedProduct);
  }
  this.resetForm(form);
}

onDelete($prdKey: string) {
  if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') == true) {
    this.ProductService.deleteProduct($prdKey);
  }
}

onItemClick(prd: Product) {
  this.ProductService.selectedProduct = Object.assign({}, prd);
}
```

```html
<form #productForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(productForm)">
  ...
</form>
<tr *ngFor="let product of productList">
  <td>{{product.prdName}}</td>
  <td>{{product.prdCat}}</td>
  <td>{{product.prdSup}}</td>
  <td><button type="button" (click)="onItemClick(product)">Update</button></td>
  <td><button type="button" *ngIf="ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey != null" (click)="onDelete(productForm) || isVisible">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you explain it more clearly, if you reproduce this issue in stackblitz it will be faster and easier to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, your delete function is expecting a product key.Just send in the `$prdKey` when you press the delete key. Remove the `*ngIf` logic, since you are already sending the particular product key. Your previous logic was to select the product key after you press the row.

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of productList">
  <td>{{product.prdName}}</td>
  <td>{{product.prdCat}}</td>
  <td>{{product.prdSup}}</td>
  <td><button type="button" (click)="onItemClick(product)">Update</button></td>
  <td><button type="button" (click)="onDelete(product.$prdKey)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Sunil Lama. It works perfectly :D